# How to see status of migrations in .NET Core with EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

The EF Core migration commands are:

```
  add     Adds a new migration.
  list    Lists available migrations.
  remove  Removes the last migration.
  script  Generates a SQL script from migrations.
```

Is there any way to see the status of available migrations (whether they were run or not)? Something like a `dotnet ef migrations status`?

Comment: Not yet. See issue [#577](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/577)

Answer (score 0):

Get-Migrations command will Displays the migrations that have been applied to the target database.

Comment: ...in EF6, but not EF Core.

Comment: Yep. I wrote it. ;-) It just lists all the available migrations, but doesn't say which ones have been applied to the database.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was **NO** for EF-versions < EF6.

To find out which commands are available run: `ef dotnet migrations help`, of which you can see the result in the question asked.

In doubt nothing prevents you to do a dumb work around and perform an 'update-database'-command to the latest version you require.

I guess since you can't "read" it to know, by (re-)imposing the migration you need, you can be sure as well.

I know, stupid suggestion. Please comment with creative ideas to get rid of this stupid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a command to check the applied migrations, but EF Core 6 creates a table called `__EFMigrationsHistory` that contains a list of migrations applied to the database.